# DateTime subtraction in ruby 2?

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-2.2

I need to subtract two `DateTime` objects in order to find out the difference in hours between them.

I try to do the following:

```
a = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 20, 16)
b = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 21, 16)
puts a - b
```

I get `(-1/1)`, the object of class `Rational`.

So, the question is, how do I find out what the difference betweent the two dates is? In hours or days, or whatever.

And what does this `Rational` mean/represent when I subtract DateTimes just like that?

#### BTW:

When I try to subtract `DateTime`'s with the difference of 1 year, I get `(366/1)`, so when I do `(366/1).to_i`, I get the number of days. But when I tried subtracting two  `DateTime`'s with the difference of 1 hour, it gave me `-1`, the number of hours. So, how do I also find out the meaning of the returned value (hours, days, years, seconds)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you **substract two datetimes**, you'll get the difference **in days**, not hours.

You get a `Rational` type for the precision (some float numbers cannot be expressed exactly with computers)

To get a number of hours, multiply the result by 24, for minutes multiply by 24*60 etc...

```
a = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 20, 16)
b = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 21, 16)

(a - b).to_i 
# days
# => -1

((a - b)* 24).to_i  
# hours
# => -24
# ...
```

[Here's a link to the official doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D)

Comment: Interestingly, I'm getting the difference in seconds

Answer (score 13):

If you do subtraction on them as a Time object it will return the result in seconds and then you can multiply accordingly to get minutes/hours/days/whatever.

```
a = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 20, 16)
b = DateTime.new(2015, 6, 21, 16)
diff = b.to_time - a.to_time    # 86400
hours = diff / 60 / 60          # 24
```